# Algebraic topology - angle function

Tags: algebraic-topology

I just know "if $f$ is continuous, $f: [a, b]\rightarrow S^1$, then there is a continuous function $g: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$, such that $f (x) = e ^ {g (x)}$, for all $x$ in $[a, b]$"

I want to solve the following exercise:

If $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb C \smallsetminus\{0\}$ is continuous, $U$ open subsset of $\mathbb C$. Prove that there exists a continuous function $g: U \rightarrow \mathbb C$ such that $f (z) = e ^ {g (z)}$, for all $z \in U$ if, and only if, for every closed path $c$ in $U$ has $ind(f \circ c, 0) = 0$.

Is it possible? how?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: Think about the topological characterization of domains $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ on which a logarithm can be defined. The function $g(z)$ here is a logarithm of $f(z)$, and hence a related topological description will emerge.

Comment: But f is not holomorphic, then can not find a branch of the logarithm in the usual way, so do not know how to proceed. 
This exercise is in a book of algebraic topology. I can not think in  primitive function.

Comment: You can find a branch of logarithm, it just may not be holomorphic. But the function $g(z)$ only needs to be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

The logarithm of a function g is defined as the integral $$\int_{\gamma} \frac {dg(z)}{z} $$

Where $\gamma$ is a curve in the domain.

This integral is well-defined, i.e., independent of path only in  simply-connected regions that do not wind around the origin.

Comment: for this I need a $C ^ 1$ path, and I just assumed a path any

Answer (score 0):

Solution

http://books.google.com.br/books?id=bFYlBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA281&lpg=PA281&dq=continuous+logarithm+exists&source=bl&ots=37yLews2np&sig=OSy-YWBS1cgbkZuBhmV-mY9bH30&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=rX3_U4yYBNL4yQSwhYHoDg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=continuous%20logarithm%20exists&f=false

From Real to Complex Analysis